# Create JSON array with single key c#

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I am working on VS2008 using .Net 3.5 framework. I am trying to create a JSON object with the below format,

```
{
  "types":["KKYQ","TGDF","YHGF"]
}
```

I tried the following code,

```
public class OutputJson
{
    public List<Types> types { get; set; }
}

public class Types
{
    public string types { get; set; }
}

public string getCodeTypes()
{
    foreach (var key in allKeys)
    {
        objToSerialize.Types.Add(new Types { types = key }); 
    }
    var objToSerialize = new OutputJson();
    var jsonOutput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objToSerialize.types);
    string finalResposne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonOutput, Formatting.None);
    return jsonOutput.Replace(@"\", "");
}
```

The above code is producing the JSON in the below format,

```
"[{\"types\":\"KKYQ\"},{\"types\":\"TGDF\"},{\"types\":\"YHGF\"}]"
```

I googled and tried with some reference from google and i am not able to achieve the output in desired format.

Please help me in getting the JSON object in below format,

```
{
  "types":["KKYQ","TGDF","YHGF"]
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class OutputJson
{
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public string getCodeTypes()
{
    var objToSerialize = new OutputJson();
    foreach (var key in allKeys)
    {
        objToSerialize.Types.Add(key); 
    }   
    var jsonOutput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objToSerialize);
    string finalResposne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonOutput, Formatting.None);
    return jsonOutput.Replace(@"\", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks@see sharper

Answer (score 4):

No need to use a separate class for *string* property.
Try following JSON object:

```
public class OutputJson
{
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}
```

Using it like:

```
OutputJson json = new OutputJson
{
    types = new List<string> {"KKYQ", "TGDF", "YHGF"}
};
string finalResposne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

Or in your case:

```
var objToSerialize = new OutputJson();
foreach (var key in allKeys)
{
    objToSerialize.types.Add(key); 
}
string finalResposne = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objToSerialize);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "types": ["KKYQ", "TGDF", "YHGF"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks FaizanRabbani

Answer (score 3):

No class needed.

```
    Console.WriteLine
    (
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject
        (
            new 
            { 
                types = new [] { "KKYQ","TGDF","YHGF"}
            }
        )
    );
```

Output:

```
{"types":["KKYQ","TGDF","YHGF"]}
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i5YWK9)